# How to use the class from added code in the jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I create html code with jquery.

```
<span id="myspan">aa</span>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click">
```

Now I want to call a function created by clicking on the code class.

```
function loadSpan()
{
var _html = "<a class=\"addItem\">test</a>";
$('#myspan').html(_html);
}
$(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){
loadSpan();
});
$('.addItem').click(function(){
alert("OK");
});
})
```

but is not working. I testing this code, and working:

```
$(function(){
loadSpan();
});
```

But I want to generate the code after clicking the button.

[test code](https://jsfiddle.net/6tv9jsr7/2/)

Comment: Why are you wrapping your click handlers in `$(function...`?

Comment: The `.addItem` element doesn't exist when `$('.addItem').click(...)` executes.  Check event delegation - https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @Innovin: There is no difference. Doesn't work in either mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event delegation on the `span` element to handle events on dynamically created elements.

```js
function loadSpan() {
  var _html = "<a class=\"addItem\">test</a>";
  $('#myspan').html(_html);
}
$('#btn').click(function() {
  loadSpan();
});
$('#myspan').on('click', '.addItem', function() {
  console.log("OK");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myspan">aa</span>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click">
```